# Failing to keep only red channel of RGB image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to keep and display only the red channel of an RGB image in MATLAB but I've some problems. I'm using the following code:

```
red = rgbimage(:,:,1)
black = zeros(size(red, 1), size(red, 2))
only_red = cat(3,red,black,black)
```

If i save as .jpg this image an then analyze with imageJ, the blue and green channel are not set to zero (as you can see in images).
[Green Channel Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uaKD.png)
[Blue Channel Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB2Dq.png)

What could be the reason?

Comment: When I run similar code, I get only red and black pixels: `rgb = rand(64,18,32); r = rgb(:,:,1); g = zeros(size(r,1),size(r,2)); img = cat(3,r,g,g); imshow(img);` Do you think you could be saving the wrong image?

Comment: jpeg is a lossy format. The number of green and blue pixels is low enough that this might be the cause. I would suggest you save the image as a png or other lossless image type and check again.

Comment: @medicine_man do you mean from a visual point of view? surely the image is visually only red but if I analyze it there is still green and blue.

Comment: @beaker it's strange because with imagej i can keep only red channel even in jpg format. Do you think that if my starting image is jpeg i can save it in loseless format? makes sense?

Comment: It sounds strange to me, too, to get color noise in a pure red image, but it's something to consider. It's probable that MATLAB and imagej are using different compression levels, so that might be why you're seeing differences. One of the options for [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#btv3cny-1-Mode) when saving jpegs is to specify `'Mode', 'lossless'`. Can you give that a try and see if there's any difference?

Comment: Also, if you're only interested in one channel, I would just save that as a grayscale image and then read it in and convert it back to RGB at the other end.